# C++ How to populate and print a vector of vector sets

Tags: c++, vector

Doing a representation of a sudoku grid, and using a vector of vectors where each grid is a set. Basically I want there to be vector of vectors to represent the grid. Each square would be a possibility of values from a set (1-9). How would I go about firstly setting the size of the vector? And then how would I print the values from the vector of vectors.

My vector variable:

```
vector<vector<set<int>>> myVector;
```

Comment: I would store the Sudoku grid just like a matrix in a single dimension vector.

Answer (score 0):

Very important thing in programming is to simplify Your tasks. You must rethink what You want to do, how You want to do it and why use this very solution to solve Your problem.

In Your case (basing on question) there is no need to use such complex, nested containers, just use for example 2 dimmensional array.

About iterationg over collections, You can use for-each loop:

```
//declaring container with base size 10
std::vector<std::vector<int>> container(5);

//for-each loop, nice way to iterate over collections
for(auto& c: container) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
        c.push_back(i);
    }
}

//printing
for(auto& c : container) {
    for(auto& v : c) {
        std::cout << v << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```